# Bootstrap Tabs Change Chart.js Default Animation

Tags: animation, chart.js

I have two Chart.js (v5.3.0-alpha1) bar graphs that show up as expected on a single page. The default animation slides both charts from the bottom to the top as you would expect.  I'm trying to put them in a Bootstrap tab setup with one chart in each tab. The charts work fine but the default slide in animations for the chart in the second tab changes and the bar graph slides in from the top left.

Anybody know why and how I can change it?  Everything I have tried so far does not work.  I can disable the animation with `duration: 0` but don't want to do that. I've also set both tabs to active which works but caused the second chart to display outside the tab.

```
cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js/dist/chart.umd.min.js
```

Bootstrap tabs:

```
            <nav>
                <div class="nav nav-tabs bg-light" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                    <a class="nav-link active fw-semibold" id="nav-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a>
                    <a class="nav-link fw-semibold" id="nav-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Tab 2</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
                    <div class="chartBox">
                        <canvas id="barchart"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
                    <div class="chartBox">
                        <canvas id="bar_exp_chart"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Simplified JavaScript for second tab:

```
                   <script>
                        const labels2 = ["A", "B", "C"];

                        const config2 = {
                            type: 'bar',
                            data: {
                                labels: labels2,
                                datasets: [{
                                            label: '["AA", "BB" , "CC"]',
                                            data: [3400, 3614, 3843]
                                }]
                            }
                        };

                        const barexpensechart = new Chart(
                            document.getElementById('bar_exp_chart'),
                            config2
                        );

                        
                    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to change the animation config, as following:

```
options: {
  animations: {
    numbers: {
      type: 'number',
      properties: ['base', 'y', 'height'],
      from: ({chart}) => chart.chartArea.bottom
    },
  }
  ...
}
```

```js
const labels2 = ["A", "B", "C"];

const config2 = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels2,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'ds',
      data: [3400, 3614, 3843]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    animations: {
      numbers: {
        type: 'number',
        properties: ['base', 'y', 'height'],
        from: ({chart}) => chart.chartArea.bottom
      },
    }
  }
};

const barexpensechart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config2
);
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.2.1/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script> 
<div class="myChartDiv">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```